# Angular 4 Primeng 4 datatable - Loading nested json

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

I am trying to load the json below into primeng datatable. I am having problem setting the column name

```
[
  {
    "accountId": 1,
    "accountName": "Environmental Service Ltd",
    "addressBook": {
      "addressBookId": 1,
      "companyId": 1,
      "addressList": [
        {
          "addressLine1": "ABC",
          "addressLine2": "XYZ",
          "addressLine3": "TUV",
          "city": "ALY",
          "postCode": "AB9 7RT"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

My code is here

```
<p-dataTable #dtAccounts [value]="accounts">
  <p-header>Accounts</p-header>
  <p-column field="accountName" header="Account Name" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="telephone" header="Account Phone" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="addressLine1" header="Street"></p-column>
  <p-column field="city" header="City"></p-column>
  <p-column field="state" header="State/Province"></p-column>
  <p-column field="postCode" header="Zip/Postal Code"/>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem you are facing? Do you mean "accountName" column?

Comment: this is wrong: `<p-column field="postCode" header="Zip/Postal Code"/>`, should be: `<p-column field="postCode" header="Zip/Postal Code"></p-column>` But it still will only populate the `accountName` in your table, based on how the JSON looks like.

Answer (score 0):

your code has some problems:

1. The data model does not match the columns definitions:

   - "telephone" field does not exist on data model
   - "state" field does not exist on data model
   - "addressLine1", "city", "postcode" does not fit the data model (they are inside an "addressList" array in a nested "addressBook" object. Each "addressList" array has nested objects with these properties)
   - `<p-column field="postCode" header="Zip/Postal Code"/>` component tag cannot be auto closed. Use `</p-column> to close <p-column ...>`.

This should work:

```
 <p-dataTable #dtAccounts [value]="accounts">
      <p-header>Accounts</p-header>
      <p-column field="accountName" header="Account Name" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
  </p-dataTable>
```

In order to render the nested address list you could user a template column, like this:

```
<p-dataTable #dtAccounts [value]="accounts" tableStyleClass="table table-hover table-striped">
                <p-header>Accounts</p-header>
                <p-column field="accountName" header="Account Name" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
                <p-column field="addressList" header="Address List">
                    <ng-template let-account="rowData" pTemplate="body">
                        <ul>
                            <li *ngFor="let address of account.addressBook.addressList">
                               {{address.addressLine1}} - {{address.addressLine2}} - {{address.city}}- {{address.postCode}}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </ng-template>
                </p-column>
            </p-dataTable>
```

Or you could consider to use another component that best fits your cenario, like [primeng/treetable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable).

I hope this helps!